# How to generate thumbnail for some pages of a PDF file?

Tags: c, pdf

I want a C library for generating image snapshots of PDF files. Then I would use this to generate the thumbnail of the first page. Is there a library for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use one of the general-purpose PDF libraries:

- [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) - C, available under the GPL
- [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) - C++, available under the GPL
- [Adobe PDF Library SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/library/) - expensive

Google reveals [quite a few](http://www.google.com/search?q=pdf+to+bmp) PDF-to-image converters which you may be able to incorporate if one of the above options doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) ---  a PDF rendering library based on the xpdf-3.0 code base. It comes with a tool to create images from PDF pages as well.